# Python Code for scraping weather information not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

city = input("Enter the city name:")
search = "Weather in {}".format(city)

url = f"http://www.google.com / search?&q ={search}"

req = requests.get(url)

sor = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

temp = sor.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text

print(temp)
```

The following is the code from geeksforgeek website for scraping of information. I am running the same in my IDE however once I enter the city name, the following error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Apratim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Apratim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Apratim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Remove the spaces in the url

Comment: it looks like it is connection error, also remember that url doesn't support space so the cities with two names won't behave the same

Comment: Thanks folks that was quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your program cannot create socket connection, it says `getaddr failed`. Because you provided an invalid URL. URL cannot contain spaces. Change

```
url = f"http://www.google.com / search?&q ={search}"
```

Into a valid URL.

```
url = f"http://www.google.com/search?&q={search}"
```

**Output**

```
$ Enter the city name:sda
Wind, waves & weather forecast Hatteras / SDA - Windfinder
```

Comment: Thank You So Much!!

Comment: @acs42 Consider accepting my answer, to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.